# How to pickle custom Python object containing Spark DataFrames as attributes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pickle

I've created a custom Python class which holds three attributes of type (Py)Spark DataFrame. The constructor of said class looks like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, df_a, df_b, df_c):
        self.a = df_a
        self.b = df_b
        self.c = df_c
```

I would like to save **an already instantiated object** of this class and be able to load it in the future. However, if I try to save it using pickle it throws a `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects` exception. As far as I understood, this exception arises because spark dataframes cannot be pickled directly.

I've looked into the function `df.rdd.saveAsPickleFile(filename)`, since I could use it to pickle independently the three dataframes, but that's not really what I want. I want to have a **single** pickle object.

*Note: whenever I'm saying pickle, I could probably work with any other serialization type, as long as it allows me to save and load a single object.*

Comment: Dataframes are typically saved using a [DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.html).

Comment: Yes, but I'm not asking about saving the dataframes, I want to save an object of MyClass